# Resize combobox arrow

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, touchscreen

I'm writing a touch screen .net winforms application and need a combobox with a larger dropdown arrow.  Is there any way to resize the arrow, or am I looking at writing a custom control?

Answer (score 1):

I think the button's size is determined by a combination of the system font size and the system scroll-bar dimensions, both of which are controlled by the display properties.

Another option is to configure the combo box to drop down when it receives focus. That way, touching anywhere on the box will make it drop down. Users might not realize that, and "aim" for the narrow button, but I see no real harm in that.

Comment: I agree that this is the easiest solution, however, there are some instances where the user will be required to fill in their selection if it is missing from the combobox choices.

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch to WPF? It's easier to make/derive custom controls in wpf. Alternatively you could just embed a WPF control in your winform.

Rolling your own control in Winforms is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JCSelector it's an open source .NET control that may help you. Go to the codeplex website at jcselector.codeplex.com